# Best way to store user id in markdown text?

Tags: mysql, parsing, text, markdown

I want to store `markdown`-based messages in mysql database.

These messages must contain `mentions` of other users:

```
**Hello**, @username.
```

And how it is visible for user

**Hello**, [@username](http://@username)

1. When user clicks on the `@username` - link must lead him to `http://example.com/users/{id}`
2. When it is stored in database - it must contain `user id` in some way, because `username` is not unique.

The question is: how to store message with additional content in markdown but do not show this additional content to user?

For example:

```
**Hello**, [@username][35].
```

Or

```
**Hello**, [@another username][123]
```

It this a good way to do it?

Comment: If `username` is not unique, then how do you determine which `user id` is intended? I was going to say you need to use that method each time you render your Markdown, but if its not unique, then how is it ever possible?

Comment: Beside this is a interesting question, it has nothing to do with markdown. The topic is more about "text" and "parsing".